# How to Do a sscanf Up to 70 Characters or a Newline

Tags: c

I would like to use sscanf to read up the 70 characters of a string or to the newline character, which ever comes first. I understand that %[^\n] allows me to read until a newline character is reached, but how would I go about of reading a maximum of 70 characters?

Comment: `"%70[^\n]"` (for char [71])

Comment: Use `fgets` and check its return value and final character.

Comment: Yes `fgets()` does exactly that...

Comment: Except for experimental code I gave up on scanf and fgets because of quirks. It makes sense to write a function measure_line and a srttok analogue for files measure_tok and a function get_measure to get the line word whatever

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution

```
#define MAXCHAR (70)
char buf[MAXCHAR + 2]; // extra for \n and for \0
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
  Handle_EOForInputError();
}
// clear potential \n
buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;
```

If you truly need to use `sscanf()`, insure `dest[0] = '\0'` to cope with the case when `buf[0] = '\n'`.  In that case `sscanf(buf, "%70[^\n]"` puts nothing in `dest`.

```
char dest[71];
dest[0] = '\0';  
sscanf(buf, "%70[^\n]", dest);
```